# WAMP server orange after inappropriate shut down

Tags: php, mysql, wamp

My computer has turned off due to power loss while the wamp server is running, now when I am trying to turn the server on it remains orange the http requests to server is working, but when I am trying to log in to MySQl I am getting the following error :

```
#2002 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

I have done some search and all the results was to remove it and reinstall is there any other way?
I am still a beginner so I don't actually know which files I need to show you in order to help me please comment of anything I need to show.

My last log in attempt in mysql log :

```
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 2671283 and 2671283 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 2671293 in the ib_logfiles!
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
2015-11-11 11:08:03 8052 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace coldatabase/item uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\coldatabase\item.ibd. Cannot open tablespace mysql/slave_relay_log_info which uses space ID: 3 at filepath: .\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd
InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\mysql\slave_relay_log_info.ibd
InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
```

Comment: Download, install, and configure [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) and use the root credentials to log into your database. It will be a far more useful debugging method than your current situation. WAMP is a tightly knit and highly finicky system which is great for newbies but it "breaks" far too easily. Later down the road I highly recommend installing Apache, PHP, and MySQL separately.

Comment: It sounds like your database has been corrupted in the system crash. Look at the `mysql log` there is a link on the wamp menu to edit that file. Add to your question what you see at the bottom of that file, just the last startup attempt

Comment: @MonkeyZeus There is nothing anymore finicky in WAMPServer or XAMPP than if you had installed everything yourself. If as it looks like in this case a database got corrupted MySQL Workbench would be of little help. If MySQL wont start MySQL Workbench wont see that databases

Comment: I have edited my question @RiggsFolly

Comment: Have you tried any of the 3 suggested fixes for the table corruption?

Comment: removing the .idb file will be like removing the whole databases right ?@RiggsFolly

Comment: Your database is corrupt, restoring it from a backup would be the perfect solution. If thats not possible (move files somewhere else, rather than delete them) and see what happens. Or try option 3, again take copies or everything so you get more than one try at it.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems and i solved it by two methods and i am mentioning the better one of the two.

1. copy c:\wamp folder to any other safe location
2. let the orginal c:\wamp folder stay in its place
3. install the wamp server from the same package that you used to install before
4. start the wamp server
5. DONE...!!!

(The copy of c:\wamp folder to any other safe location was just for emergency, in case something goes wrong).